# Extracting certain parts of a webpage using PyQt5 and displaying them

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I want to make GUI application which asks the user for the champion they want to check and then their role (e.g Middle, Jungle, Top, ADC, Support) and then it will display the "Most Frequent Runes" and some other data on the website. I believe PyQt5 would be the best python GUI for this as it has embedded webpages but please suggest alternatives.

With this code:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
import sys

#champion = input("What champion would you like to check? ")
champions = "Katarina"
#role = input("What role are you playing (Middle, Jungle, Top, ADC, Support)? ")
roles = "Middle"
URL = f"https://champion.gg/champion/{champions.capitalize()}/{roles.capitalize()}?"

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

web = QWebEngineView()
web.load(QUrl(URL))
web.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

It displays the whole webpage but I only want the "Most frequent Runes" section shown like it is like this:

[image]

and then hold it as a variable (QLabel?) that can then be placed wherever I want it. I have tried to look over how to do this but i couldn't find a solution. I would rather have done it using tkinter but it seems that isn't possible (or as far as I have been able to gather - if their is a way please explain as much as you can how).

I tried scraping the website using bs4 and requests with this code:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time
import sys

#champion = input("What champion would you like to check? ")
champions = "Katarina"
#role = input("What role are you playing (Middle, Jungle, Top, ADC, Support)? ")
roles = "Middle"
URL = f"https://champion.gg/champion/{champions.capitalize()}/{roles.capitalize()}?"

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

page = requests.get('https://champion.gg/champion/Katarina/Middle?')

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')

championData = soup.find('div', 'summoner-text')


window = QWidget()


window.setWindowTitle("League of Legends helper")
window.setGeometry(100, 100, 550, 250)


runes = QLabel(championData, parent=window)
```

but it just produces errors which I haven't fully been able to understand.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "(FILEPATH)", line 32, in <module>
    runes = QLabel(championData, parent=window)
TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  QLabel(parent: QWidget = None, flags: Union[Qt.WindowFlags, Qt.WindowType] = Qt.WindowFlags()): argument 1 has unexpected type 'Tag'
  QLabel(str, parent: QWidget = None, flags: Union[Qt.WindowFlags, Qt.WindowType] = Qt.WindowFlags()): argument 1 has unexpected type 'Tag'
```

Answer (score 1):

BeautifulSoup's is an HTML parser so each node of the DOM has a wrapper that allows access to its properties, so championData is not a string causing the error.

Even so, you would extract the HTML from the node, it would be useless because the "requests" library does not obtain the HTML generated dynamically by javascript, in addition, the styles would not be kept as they depend on other files.

A possible solution for this case is to extract the HTML from that node and place it in the same document using javascript:

```py
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets


def main(*, champions, roles):
    url = f"https://champion.gg/champion/{champions.capitalize()}/{roles.capitalize()}?"

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    web = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()
    web.resize(640, 480)

    progress_dialog = QtWidgets.QProgressDialog()
    progress_dialog.setLabelText(
        """""<p><span style=" font-size:20pt; font-weight:600;">Loadding ...</span></p>"""
    )
    progress_dialog.resize(640, 480)
    progress_dialog.show()

    web.loadProgress.connect(progress_dialog.setValue)

    button = progress_dialog.findChild(QtWidgets.QPushButton)
    if button is not None:
        button.clicked.connect(QtCore.QCoreApplication.quit)

    def on_load_finished():
        codes = [
            """var iterator = document.evaluate("/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null)""",
            """var e = iterator.iterateNext() """,
            """document.body.innerHTML = e.innerHTML""",
            """document.body.children[0].style.marginTop = "10px" """,
        ]
        for code in codes:
            web.page().runJavaScript(code)
        web.move(progress_dialog.pos())
        web.show()
        progress_dialog.close()

    web.loadFinished.connect(on_load_finished)
    web.load(QtCore.QUrl(url))

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(champions="Katarina", roles="Middle")
```

[image]

Update:

```py
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self._champion_le = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(placeholderText=self.tr("champion"))
        self._role_cb = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        self._web = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()
        self._search_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tr("Search"))
        self._stacked = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
        self._progress_bar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar()

        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        lay = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(central_widget)
        lay.addWidget(self._champion_le, 0, 0)
        lay.addWidget(self._role_cb, 0, 1)
        lay.addWidget(self._search_btn, 0, 2)
        lay.addWidget(self._stacked, 1, 0, 1, 3)

        container = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(container)
        lay.addWidget(
            QtWidgets.QLabel(
                self.tr(
                    """<p><span style="font-size:20pt; font-weight:600;">Loadding ...</span></p>"""
                )
            )
        )
        lay.addWidget(self._progress_bar)

        self._stacked.addWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget())
        self._stacked.addWidget(container)
        self._stacked.addWidget(self._web)

        self._role_cb.addItems(["Top", "Jungle", "Middle", "ADC", "Support"])
        self._search_btn.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked)
        self._web.loadFinished.connect(self.on_load_finished)
        self._web.loadProgress.connect(self._progress_bar.setValue)

        self.resize(640, 480)

        self._champion_le.setText("Aatrox")
        self._role_cb.setCurrentText("Top")

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_clicked(self):
        champion = self._champion_le.text()
        role = self._role_cb.currentText()
        if champion:
            self._stacked.setCurrentIndex(1)
            self.change(champion, role)

    def change(self, champion, role):
        url = f"https://champion.gg/champion/{champion.capitalize()}/{role}?"
        self._web.load(QtCore.QUrl(url))

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(bool)
    def on_load_finished(self, ok):
        if ok:
            codes = [
                """var iterator = document.evaluate("/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null)""",
                """var e = iterator.iterateNext() """,
                """document.body.innerHTML = e.innerHTML""",
                """document.body.children[0].style.marginTop = "10px" """,
            ]
            for code in codes:
                self._web.page().runJavaScript(code)
            self._stacked.setCurrentIndex(2)


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, thats really good. How did you figure out how to grab sections of a webpage? Also, My main idea is to make an application that allows the user to type in the champion they want and the role they want (through a GUI - which is a key point), then go to a frame that shows multiple sections of a webpage, not just the runes so something [like this](https://gyazo.com/53959b043bf2a7b8dd034c1b744dd5c8) .

Comment: So as far as i'm aware, PyQt doesn't fully have that capability so I went with tkinter but have met so many road blocks that its starting to seem almost impossible especially since i'm somewhat new to Python and bs4.
I just really cant't seem to find the right help links to do the stuff that I want to do in Python. it may be that I am not searching properly but likewise with your code @eyllanesc , I really don't understand most of the code.

Comment: @AhmedM 1) I had to use XPATH although I think it can be implemented using the field name. 2) PyQt has this capacity, you could support it because you think it is not capable of doing it (a sample of it is my answer), I am going to adapt my code so that you can choose the champion and role, the other things you will have to learn to do yourself. 3) If you are new to a technology then you will have to work on it: try simpler projects

Comment: I mean thanks for everything you've done but is it really possible to display more than one section of a webpage in a user-friendly GUI with PyQt5? I mean even separating a webpage into sections and only displaying a section you want (like what you have done), seemed impossible when I looked it up.

Comment: Where can i learn PyQt5 to your extent of knowledge? Even when looking at Python documentation, I get confused and don't understand it. So far i've learnt the basics with YouTube tutorials but that only takes you so far.

Comment: @AhmedM 4) The documentation serves to know the task of the elements of technology (functions, classes, etc) but our job is to use these basic tools for our purpose as I did. 5) My solution is really simple: QWebEngineView allows to implement a browser so I can inject javascript code so when loading the page it uses javascript to find the div, then I get the HTML of that div and I put it as body, then I modify the css to modify some visual aspects, that is to say QWebEngineView allows me to use javascript

Comment: So it's as if you reconstructed a new webpage with the aspects of the original URL? I think thats a great idea...So i can display more than just the runes in a html sort of format i suspect?
This is my current tkinter code: https://codeshare.io/5XEApM

Comment: @AhmedM You want to run when you do not know or crawl, if you do not know python then it is difficult to correctly use some python-based technology such as tkinter or pyqt5. My recommendation: Keep reviewing tutorials (Do not use YT since to learn to show a window you have to consume 10 minutes of your life, instead use the thousands of online tutorials that with a copy-paste you will learn the same but with less time), review the Qt docs, take the time to consolidate basic knowledge (learning takes time and dedication).

Comment: Could you possibly add a few comments to your code? It would help a lot to understand the more complicated aspects of the code (e.g: `on_load_finished()` function)

Comment: Thanks, I really do want to learn Python since it seems that it can really help with automation and I really love programming (even though it can be extremely frustration at times).

Comment: @AhmedM As I already pointed out, my code is very simple: - When loading the page, on_load_finished is called, - In that function I execute the javascrip code, which is to find the "div" that has the information and hides the other data.

Comment: With the input, how would i go about that?, do i just write html code to accept an input? and then set it to `main(champions="Aatrox", roles="Top")`?